# Morphisms from injective to preprojective modules for non-Dynkin quivers

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

Let $Q$ be a quiver without oriented cycles. Suppose in addition that $Q$ is non-Dynkin. I am looking for the reference or proof of the following fact:

Let $I$ be an injective $kQ$-module and $M$ be a preprojective $kQ$-module. Then $Hom_{kQ}(I, M)=0.$

For Dynkin quivers this shouldn't be true. For example, let

$$Q = 2 \stackrel{a}\longrightarrow 1$$
and denote $A:=kQ$.

Then we have a nontrivial $A$-module map $f:A^*\to A$ such that $f(e_1^*)=a, f(a^*)=e_2$ and $f(e_2^*)=0.$

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that $Hom_{KQ}(M,P)=0$ for any non-projective indecomposable module $M$ and any projective module $P$.

Let $f:M\to P$ be a non-zero map.  Then we have a short exact sequence
$$ 0\to \ker(f)\to M\to \mathrm{im}(f)\to 0.$$

$\mathrm{im}(f)$ is a submodule of $P$, so the fact that $KQ$ is hereditary means that $\mathrm{im}(f)$ is projective.  Since $\mathrm{Ext}_A^1( X, Y)=0$ for any algebra $A$, any projective $A$-module $X$, and any $A$-module $Y$.  The short exact sequence above splits.  Since $M$ is indecomposable, splitness implies that $M\cong \mathrm{im}(f)$, so $M$ is projective.

Comment: Where did you use that the quiver $Q$ is non-Dynkin?

Comment: You don't need restriction on $Q$ as long as it is finite acyclic; the property you need is that $KQ$ is hereditary, I.e. Submodule of a projective is again projective.

Comment: Your example fails because the it has a projective-injective module, the statement you want holds for Dynkin type too as long as it is not a Nakayama algebra. Read again the statement I was trying to prove.

Comment: Okay, I see. For $A_2$ quiver example, the injective module $A^*$ is the direct sum of modules $A^*e_1$ and $A^*e_2$. The first module is isomorphic to $Ae_1$ and the second one is not projective, in particular $Hom_A(A^*e_2,A)=0$ and $Ext_A^1(A^*e_2,A)$ is 1-dimensional.

Comment: What if $P$ is a pre-projective module?

Comment: You can show, using a "dual" argument, that $Hom_{KQ}(I,M)=0$ for any indecomposable injective module $I$ and any non-injective indecomposable module $M$.  Note that the opposite algebra $(KQ)^{op}$ is isomorphic (as an algebra) to the path algebra $KQ^{op}$ of the opposite quiver $Q^{op}$, so hereditary also means that any quotient (=$KQ^{op}$-submodule) of an injective $KQ$-module (=projective $KQ^{op}$-module) is also injective.